# Talend - mysql components vs amazon mysql components

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, talend

I have migrated my MYSQL databases to Amazon RDS. I am trying to get the data from SQL server to Amazon RDS mysql through talend. However, the jobs run very slow. A 50000 rows insertion takes an hour of time. Whereas, when I use the Talend Amazon components, tAmazonMysqlOutput, the same job completes in less than a minute

May I know what is the reason for this? If I change all my regular mysql components to Amazon mysql components would there be any issues?

Any ideas on this would be of great help

Thanks
Rathi

Comment: I don't understand this. If it runs faster with the Amazon components, switch them and see if there are errors. Why not just try it first?

Comment: I have tried already and its faster with Amazon components. My question was why is it slow with the regular mysql components?

Comment: I suppose Amazon is doing something which is different than standard MySQL databases and the components compensate for that. If you can read Java, the source code might be available.